# ModelForm doesn't manage instance model as I need

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, models

My problem is that I want to manage dialogue attributes using ModelForm. Now I need to realize adding in dialogue participants and changing name of dialogue. I tried to do it using code below but when I add participants dialogue name is becoming empty string. Changing name simply doesn't work.

My question is why change_name method has no effect and why after adding new participants - name of dialogue becomes empty string.

This dialogue model contains methods which I use for changing name - (def change_name) and adding participants (def add_participants):

```
class Dialogue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_conference = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notifications_on = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name='+',
        null=True,
    )
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name='dialogues',
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or str(self.pk)

    def add_participants(self, *args):
        new_participants = args
        for new_participant in new_participants:
            self.participants.add(new_participant)
        return self

    def remove_participants(self, *args):
        participants = args
        for participant in participants:
            self.participants.remove(participant)
        return self

    def change_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name
        return self
```

In this ModelForm I create Dialogue with is_conference attribute which always equals true. I divided two opportunities: when I create conference and when I manage existing conference. So I have problems with second part. I tried to remove part where I call function change_name but anyway dialogue name is becoming empty after I add new participants.

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dialogue
        fields = ['name', 'participants']

    def __init__(self, person, *args, **kwargs):
        self.person = person
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CreateConferenceForm, self).clean()
        if self.instance not in self.person.dialogues.all():
            dialogue = Dialogue(creator=self.person,     name=cleaned_data.get('name'), is_conference=True)
            dialogue.save()
            dialogue.add_participants(self.person, *cleaned_data.get('participants'))
        else:
            dialogue = self.instance
            if cleaned_data.get('name'):
                dialogue.change_name(cleaned_data.get('name'))
            dialogue.save()
            if len(cleaned_data.get('participants')):                               
                dialogue.add_participants(*cleaned_data.get('participants'))
```

This view renders page with ModelForm:

```
def dialogue(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    sel = request.GET.get('sel')
    act = request.GET.get('act')
    try:
        managable_dialogue = person.dialogues.filter(is_conference=True)[int(sel[1:])-1]
        form = CreateConferenceForm(instance=managable_dialogue, person=person)
        new_available_participants = person.friends
        for person in managable_dialogue.participants.all():
            new_available_participants = new_available_participants.exclude(id=person.id)
        form.fields['participants'].queryset = new_available_participants.all()
        return render(request, 'dialogues/dialogue_creation.html', {
            'form': form,
            'act': act,
            'sel': sel,
        })
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/im')
```

And the second view takes POST data from previous view and save changes. I tested a result of is_valid here and it's false if I only change dialogue name but it's true if I only add participants. Both changes I didn't test yet because I need only separate changes:

```
def edit(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    sel = request.POST.get('sel')
    data = request.POST
    try:
        managable_dialogue = person.dialogues.filter(is_conference=True)[int(sel[1:]) - 1]
        form_data = CreateConferenceForm(instance=managable_dialogue, person=person, data=data)
        if form_data.is_valid():
            form_data.save()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/im?sel='+sel)
```

And as a result adding new participants overwrites dialogue name to empty string but new participants are added, and changing dialogue name simply has no effect.

Comment: I can't understand your question at all. But all those methods on the model are pointless; it is simpler and quicker to set the attributes directly from your view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But what about incapsulation and making a good abstraction? My question is why change_name method has no effect and why after adding new participants - name of dialogue becomes empty string.

Comment: The model is already an abstraction, I don't know why you think you need to add more on top of it. Please follow the tutorial for an example of how these things are done in Python.